# The correct word order in the main clause of the "wenn" clause

Tags: word-order

{Why the need to say}:

> ... doch **wollte** diese Person für Gerechtigkeit **kämpfen**, **sie gäbe** besser von vornherein auf.

{instead of}:

> ... doch **wollte** diese Person für Gerechtigkeit **kämpfen**, **gäbe sie** besser von vornherein auf.

---

I assume the first part of the sentence is a *wenn* clause that goes like:

> ... doch **wenn** diese Person für Gerechtigkeit kämpfen wollte, ...

So the main clause needs to take the Verb-Subject word order, correct? I wonder why the Subject-Verb word order "sie gäbe" is considered correct in this instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only can guess if your quote is taken from a play, but if so it is very likely that the author wanted to emphazise the main clause.

To achieve this it is helpful to change the (correct) word order in this case to

> ...doch wollte diese Person für Gerechtigkeit kämpfen, **sie gäbe** besser von vornherein auf.

for two reasons:

1. Through changing the order into a *normal* main clause order, this part can actually be read or spoken like a single main clause, which leads to number
2. that if ones sees that the following sentence is a main clause in Subject-Verb word order, one can choose to take a break after the comma which can be considerably longer than in

> ... doch wollte diese Person für Gerechtigkeit kämpfen, **gäbe sie** besser von vornherein auf.

So the comma in the first case acts stronger than the comma in the second case.

Comment: +1, and the *Reihung* is a stylistic feature, too. The orginal sentence is open to append more sentences of the same kind, to continue the speech, while the example in "standard" word order is closing the speech.